# gettting "org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@c91f0d" this error in Java Script

Tags: java, javascript

```
var rs = dbConn.executeCachedQuery("select ....");
var rsmd;
var colCount;
```

after hitting this query i am getting 3 result

```
 while(rs.next()) {
    logger.info('entering...'+(count + 1));
    var columnName,patientID,value,text = '';
    rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    colCount  = rsmd.getColumnCount();


    for (var i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
        columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        value      = rs.getObject(i);
        //doing some task here
    }
    //end of FOR loop
 }
 //end of while loop
```

my query returns 3 rows,after looping through 3 rows while checking 'rs.next()' in WHILE condition, it is throwing below error..

while executing this i am getting this error `org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@c91f0d`
please help

Comment: Did you try to loop 0 to i < colCount ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop from 0 to i < colCount. In JavaScript, and many other language, the indexing starts from zero.

Look:

[Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)